# R import all but a couple of functions

Tags: r, package

I am working on the upgrade to [ggtern](http://ggtern.com) to handle ggplot 2.0.X, I need to import the grid package, however, ggplot2 is now exporting `arrow` and `unit` functions, which generates warnings when my package is loaded:

```
Warning messages:
1: replacing previous import by ‘grid::arrow’ when loading ‘ggtern’ 
2: replacing previous import by ‘grid::unit’ when loading ‘ggtern’
```

Is it possible to import the library with the exception of a couple of functions, ie something to the effect of the following might be useful in roxygen:

```
#' @importAllExcept grid arrow unit
```

Which should have the same effect as the following, (minus importing `arrow` and `unit`):

```
#' @import grid
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Currently my best idea is `all <- getNamespaceExports("grid"); paste("@importFrom grid", paste(all[!(all %in% c("arrow", "unit"))], collapse = " "))`. That's obviously not a good solution, but unlike for exports you can't use a regex for imports, i.e., there is no `importPatternFrom`.

Comment: that did the trick, cheers...

Comment: @Roland can you post it as an answer ?

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently my best idea is

```
all <- getNamespaceExports("grid")
paste("@importFrom grid", paste(all[!(all %in% c("arrow", "unit"))], collapse = " ")) 
#[1] "@importFrom grid grid.edit pop.viewport ...
```

That's obviously not a good solution, but unlike for exports you can't use a regex for imports, i.e., there is no `importPatternFrom`.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is a very late answer but I guess this still can help someone.

Since [roxygen2 v5.0](https://www.rstudio.com/blog/roxygen2-5-0-0/) (2015), you can use this syntax:

```r
#' @rawNamespace import(grid, except=c(arrow, unit))
```

This will add the exact same text in `NAMESPACE`, which is exactly what you need.